# Invalid handler method return value: ModelAndView: reference to view with name in spring MVC

Tags: rest, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I am unable to return view information from ExcepitonHandler method.

MY Controller Exception Handler Method. Its in the same controller.

```
@ExceptionHandler(EmpNotFoundException.class)
public ModelAndView empNFound(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest, Exception exception) {
    System.out.println("Emp NOt FOund Ex");
    ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();
    modelAndView.addObject("exp", exception);
    modelAndView.setViewName("error");
    return modelAndView;
}
```

If I return a string "error" its rendering the error.jsp, but not working with when i send it in ModelAndView.

Error.jsp

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<%@ page session="false"%>
<html>
<head>
<title>Home</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h2>Application Error, please contact support.</h2>
    <h3>This is error page</h3>
</body>
</html>
```

EmpNotFoundException.java

```
@ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND)
public class EmpNotFoundException extends RuntimeException {

    public EmpNotFoundException() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public EmpNotFoundException(String message) {
        super(message);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

}
```

Throwing the below exception in logs.

```
Aug 09, 2018 7:37:28 AM org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerExceptionResolver doResolveException
SEVERE: Invoking request method resulted in exception : public org.springframework.web.portlet.ModelAndView com.springtopics.controllers.EmployeeController.empNFound(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,java.lang.Exception)
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid handler method return value: ModelAndView: reference to view with name 'error'; model is {exp=com.springtopics.exceptions.EmpNotFoundException: Employee Not Found:4}
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerExceptionResolver.getModelAndView(AnnotationMethodHandlerExceptionResolver.java:419)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerExceptionResolver.doResolveException(AnnotationMethodHandlerExceptionResolver.java:149)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerExceptionResolver.resolveException(AbstractHandlerExceptionResolver.java:137)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processHandlerException(DispatcherServlet.java:1182)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1020)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:971)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:969)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:860)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:624)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:845)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:110)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:494)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:169)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:104)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:1025)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:445)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1136)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:637)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:318)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

This is the browser output.
[image]

please let me konw where I am missing.

Comment: Check the stacktrace you are using `org.springframework.web.portlet.ModelAndView` whereas you probably want `org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView`. Which also makes me wonder what your setup is as you are also using the deprecated `AnnotationMethodHandlerExceptionResolver` (and you state you are using Spring Boot).

Comment: Thank you very much for your time, It was a wrong import by mistake. Now I import correct ModelAndView, its working fine. Thank you.